# Linux server crashing (drm:drm_fb_helper_panic)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, server-crashes

We have a server (IBM x3850 8864) running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It's acting as a KVM host with several virtual machines on it (also running Ubuntu 10.04). The (physical) server sometimes crashes with error messages like

[image: crash output]

Checking monitoring graphs, there's no high load or any other unnormal thing going on before the crash. This kind of crash happens every 2-3 months. In our situation, it is too rare to just throw the box away, but too often to ignore the problem. So my questions are:

- What do these error messages mean?
- If it's not possible to tell from the error message what the problem is, what would be some next steps to investigate this issue further?

Comment: It would help if you would scroll up... :)